# Simple mysql select slower in java than in MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, scala, jdbc

My scala code running a select performs an order of magnitude slower than issuing the same query on MySQL Workbench. The time between my debug prints `connection made` and `query returned` is exceptionally long compared to the same query in MySQL Workbench, all other steps are fast. Of course I am using the same database user in both cases.

```
import java.sql.{Connection,DriverManager,ResultSet}

object JavaSQL extends App {

  val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val url = ..
  val user = ..
  val password = ..

  println("loading driver")
  Class.forName(driver) // loads the driver
  println("driver loaded")

  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
  println("connection made")

  val rs: ResultSet = connection.createStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Foo")
  println("query returned")

  connection.close

}
```

build.sbt:

```
lazy val project = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38")
  )
```

What should I basically do to get it at par? It is as slow as running the same query in mysql's command-line. Workbench must be using some special flags.

I've used JDBC/SQL abstractions for a while and now returning to java.sql so please be gentle..

Comment: Are you counting the time it takes to make the connection with the database? Also, JVM warmup.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've clarified it now in the question. I think the answer is no. Everything is quick other than that step I describe.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you compare the performance of a query that only returns one row instead of returning many rows, e.g., `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Foo`?

Comment: Matter solved, see below, thanks though!

Comment: Actually, would be nice executing the query such that code that consumes it does not wait for the whole table to stream through... but that's diverging from the original topic a little.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench uses a default limit of 1000 rows. That's all.